# Theming a Field Collection Widget

Tags: entities

Is it possible to theme the Field Collection widget for just one field? The example I am looking for is a list of text fields. I need some of the text fields to be in two columns instead of one long column, which is the default. I also need to add some formatting guide text for some of the fields. I know I can achieve some of this through CSS, but was curious if there is a hook or something that I could implement that would allow me to change the markup as well? This is in Drupal 7 as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

You need to go to the Field Collection module directory and copy `field-collection-item.tpl.php`. Then paste it into your theme directory and rename it to `field-collection-item--myfieldname.tpl.php`.

Comment: Then clear the caches :)

Comment: This is great for styling the output of the field, thank you! I realize now I should have been more clear. I was looking to style the entry form for the field collection. Is this possible? As in when they are on node/edit/# can I change the form that is displayed for a field collection field? Thank you again though as your tip was still useful to me!